# Algorithm for rearranging and inserting n-long value into row of 2D matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

having 2D matrix where:

- 0 represents empty space
- other numbers represent blocks (#7 is block of 3 spaces in example bellow)
- block can span across rows, but not columns
- block can be of any size in row
- space can be marked with 1 number only

Block can be verified as insertable if column of matrix contains at least one empty space for each space in block being inserted.
Task is to insert new block with minimum rearrangements/modifications to original matrix.

For example:

```
1 1 0 2 2 6
3 0 4 4 5 5
7 7 7 0 8 8
↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
0 1 1 1 0 0 - Insertable mask

0 9 9 9 0 0 - Block being inserted

Wanted result - 3 modifications necessary (block #7, #3, #1):
7 7 7 2 2 6
1 1 4 4 5 5
3 0 0 0 8 8
```

When having matrix with size 48x20 brute force is no longer viable.
What concept or approach should I use to develop algorithm solving this problem?

Comment: It would be interesting to see what the 48x20 problem looks like. I'm thinking that the same techniques used to solve Sudoku puzzles can be applied here.